# Google AppScript Chatbot not responding to Users

Tags: chatbot, google-hangouts

I have developed a Google app-script chatbot, which responds to users over hangout. The Script uses Gmail and Drive Services. The Chatbot correctly responds to my messages, whereas it doesn't work for other users, though the bot has been shared with them.

What are the possible reasons for the same, am I missing any dependency or Authorization.

Answer (score -1):

If your Google Apps Script chat bot is responding to your messages but not to messages from other users, there could be several reasons for this issue. Here are some possible reasons and troubleshooting steps to address the problem:

- Ensure that the script has the necessary authorization and permissions to access Gmail and Drive services on behalf of all users.
- Check that you've correctly shared the script with other users and that they have access to the script. Make sure they have at least "View" or "Edit" access as required.
- If you're using a web app as the interface for your chat bot, ensure that it's published and deployed correctly. Other users should have access to the web app's URL.
- Check the deployment settings to ensure it's accessible by "Anyone" or "Anyone within your organization," depending on your requirements.
  Authorization Prompt:
- Other users might need to grant permissions for the chat bot to access their Gmail and Drive data. The first time they interact with the bot, they should see an authorization prompt. Make sure they accept it.
  Script Functionality:
- Review your script to ensure it doesn't have any specific logic that only responds to your user or specific conditions.
- Check if the bot is using any user-specific data or settings that might cause it to behave differently for each user.
  Error Handling:
- Implement error handling in your script to catch and log any errors or issues that might occur during execution. This can help identify the root cause of problems.
  Logging and Debugging:
- Add logging statements to your script to track the execution flow and any potential issues.
- Use the script editor's built-in debugging tools to test and troubleshoot the script's behavior.
- Test the chat bot with multiple test users to identify if the issue is specific to certain users or a broader problem.
- Ensure that your script's dependencies, such as libraries or external APIs, are up to date and functioning correctly.
  Script Execution Limitations:
- Be aware of Google Apps Script execution limitations, such as execution time and quota limits. Ensure your script doesn't exceed these limits.
  Review Access Scopes:
- Double-check that your script has the necessary access scopes configured for the Gmail and Drive services it uses.
- If the issue persists after checking these points, it might be beneficial to seek assistance from the Google Workspace support team or the Google Apps Script community forums. They can provide more specific guidance and solutions based on the details of your script and deployment.

***Also for me after resolving all these issues, still it was not working for other users, so finally instead of updating the deployment I deployed the app-script with a new deployment ID, and it worked for other users.***